# Timeout Invoke-Command Background Child Jobs

Tags: powershell, background-process, jobs

I'm creating a controller script that will run audit scripts contained in separate .ps1 files. I'm using `Invoke-Command` to kick off jobs on target servers. I know that this will create child jobs for each target computer. How can I timeout individual child jobs if they run too long (ex: 2 minutes)? I know there's `Wait-Job -Timeout <seconds>`, but that won't really work for my scenario since I want to also print out progress.
Below is what I've tried so far, however the timeout doesn't appear to function.

Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

```
    Write-Host "Queueing job... " -NoNewline
    Invoke-Command -FilePath $JobFilePath -ComputerName $Targets -AsJob -ThrottleLimit 16 -JobName "AuditJob" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Job | Wait-job -Timeout 15} -ComputerName $Targets -AsJob -ThrottleLimit 16 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green

    $origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition

    [Console]::CursorVisible = $false
    
    $Completed      = 0
    $NotStarted     = 0
    $Running        = 0
    $Stopped        = 0
    $Failed         = 0
    $Blocked        = 0
    $Total          = 0
    $JobsComplete   = 0
    
    $CompleteStrLength = 0

    do{
        $Job            = Get-Job -Name "AuditJob" -IncludeChildJob -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "AuditJob"}
        $Completed      = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Completed"}).Count
        $NotStarted     = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "NotStarted"}).Count
        $Running        = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"}).Count
        $Stopped        = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Stopped"}).Count
        $Failed         = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Failed"}).Count
        $Blocked        = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Blocked"}).Count
    
        $Total = $Completed + $NotStarted + $Running +$Stopped + $Failed + $Blocked
        $JobsComplete = $Total - $NotStarted - $Running
        $PercentComplete = $JobsComplete/$Total

        $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
        
        Write-Host "[In Progress: $Running || Completed: $Completed || Not Started: $NotStarted || Failed: $($Stopped + $Failed + $Blocked)]"
        $CurrentPos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
        Write-Host (' ' * $CompleteStrLength)
        $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $CurrentPos
        
        $CompleteStr = "$([Math]::Ceiling($PercentComplete * 100))% complete"
        $CompleteStrLength = $CompleteStr.Length
        Write-Host $CompleteStr
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250 #helps with excessive flashing

    }while ($JobsComplete -ne $Targets.Count)
```

Comment: When you say you want to timeout the job on the remote machine. Do you mean you want to stop/kill that job from running if it exceeds the timeout limit? Or you just want to consider it a failed job to update your output and so that loop isn't running forever?

Comment: @kconsiglio I guess both. I'd want to kill the job on that remote machine so it stops running, and also consider it a failed job so I can update my output and prevent it from running forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think one issue is with your second `Invoke-Command`. From what I understand the job is being created on your local computer, so that command won't really be doing anything since you are trying to wait for a job that won't exist on the target computer. Using `Wait-Job` might work locally but getting it to work while your interface is being updated at the same time could be tricky since it pauses the script until the set **timeout** is reached.

To work around this I created a `foreach` loop inside your loop to go through the job objects. For each job object, I got start time of the job using the `PSBeginTime` property and got the elapsed time by subtracting that from the current time using `Get-date`. If that elapsed is over your set **timeout** you can use `Stop-Job` to stop the job.

It does stop the job on the remote machine from continuing and will report on your output as **failed**. Could require more testing if your remote job is launching an .exe or something as I only tested with a powershell script.

```
$JobFilePath = ""
$targets = ""
# change as required
$timeOutSeconds = 2
Write-Host "Queueing job... " -NoNewline

Write-Host "Queueing job... " -NoNewline
    Invoke-Command -FilePath $JobFilePath -ComputerName $targets -AsJob -ThrottleLimit 16 -JobName "AuditJob" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    # remove line
    # Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Job | Wait-job -Timeout 15} -ComputerName $Targets -AsJob -ThrottleLimit 16 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green

    $origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition

    [Console]::CursorVisible = $false
    
    $Completed      = 0
    $NotStarted     = 0
    $Running        = 0
    $Stopped        = 0
    $Failed         = 0
    $Blocked        = 0
    $Total          = 0
    $JobsComplete   = 0
    
    $CompleteStrLength = 0

    do{
        $Job            = Get-Job -Name "AuditJob" -IncludeChildJob -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "AuditJob"}
        $Completed      = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Completed"}).Count
        $NotStarted     = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "NotStarted"}).Count
        $Running        = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"}).Count
        $Stopped        = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Stopped"}).Count
        $Failed         = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Failed"}).Count
        $Blocked        = ($Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Blocked"}).Count

        foreach ($checkJOb in $Job){   
            
        # if job is not started yet time will be null and will error out
        if ($null -ne $checkJOb.PSBeginTime){
                
            # calculate elapsed time in seconds.
            $totalSecondsElapsed = ((Get-Date) - ($checkJOb.PSBeginTime)).TotalSeconds

            # check if time elapsed has passed timeout threshold
            if ($totalSecondsElapsed -ge $timeOutSeconds){               

                # stop the current job
                Stop-Job  -id  $checkJOb.id             

            }
        }     
            
            
        }
    
        $Total = $Completed + $NotStarted + $Running +$Stopped + $Failed + $Blocked
        $JobsComplete = $Total - $NotStarted - $Running
        $PercentComplete = $JobsComplete/$Total

        $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
        
        Write-Host "[In Progress: $Running || Completed: $Completed || Not Started: $NotStarted || Failed: $($Stopped + $Failed + $Blocked)]"
        $CurrentPos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
        Write-Host (' ' * $CompleteStrLength)
        $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $CurrentPos
        
        $CompleteStr = "$([Math]::Ceiling($PercentComplete * 100))% complete"
        $CompleteStrLength = $CompleteStr.Length
        Write-Host $CompleteStr
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250 #helps with excessive flashing

    }while ($JobsComplete -ne $Targets.Count)
```